# Cancellation token not working in .NET6 WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-6.0, cancellation-token

I have a simple .NET6 WinForms app that creates a system tray icon with one menu item: Exit. The app spawns an async task to manage a named pipe that receives and logs messages from a Windows Service. If the user clicks the Exit menu item, the event handler cancels the token, however the named pipe `WaitForConnectionsAsync` call doesn't recognize the cancellation.

I have tried many variations on the startup sequence. In this case I thought I might need `configureAwait(false)` for the named pipe thread, but it still doesn't work. Scattering around debug messages shows that the UI portion does properly exit and the token *is* canceled, but the named pipe class never exits the `WaitForConnectionAsync` call.

**Program.cs**

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    private static SystemTrayApp trayApp = null;
    private static CancellationTokenSource ctsMessageServer = new();

    [STAThread] 
    static void Main() 
        => MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        List<Task> tasks = new();

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            trayApp = new SystemTrayApp();
            Application.Run(trayApp);
        }));

        tasks.Add(Task.Run(async Task () =>
        {
            await MessageServer.RunServer(ctsMessageServer.Token).configureAwait(false);
        }));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    public static void Exit()
    {
        ctsMessageServer.Cancel();
        trayApp.Dispose();
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

**MessageServer.cs** (partial)

```cs
internal static class MessageServer
{
    private static readonly string pipeServerName = "fubar";
    private static readonly string separatorControlCode = "\u0014";

    public static async Task RunServer(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            while(!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                using var server = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeServerName, PipeDirection.In);

                await server.WaitForConnectionAsync(cancellationToken);
                cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    // omitted the rest, never reaches the line above
    // below: reading the data, disconnect, catch blocks, etc.
```

Nothing interesting in `SystemTrayApp` -- it just creates the icon and menu, and the Exit event-handler disposes some internal objects, then calls `Program.Exit` shown above.

For the `MessageServer` class, I know all of that code is correct and works, I've used it in many other projects ([example](https://github.com/MV10/CommandLineSwitchPipe)), and I've used async/await and cancellation tokens in many scenarios over the years, including complex multi-threaded WPF apps. I assume something is different with WinForms in the picture...

Comment: The `NamedPipeServerStream` has a method [EndWaitForConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.endwaitforconnection?view=net-7.0#system-io-pipes-namedpipeserverstream-endwaitforconnection(system-iasyncresult)) could be that you need to explicitly call that, but I do wonder what the token is used for then.

Comment: Also found this piece of documentation which might help `Cancellation requests using the cancellation token will only work if the NamedPipeServerStream object was created with a pipe option value of PipeOptions.Asynchronous or if the cancellation occurs before the WaitForConnectionAsync method is called.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Remarks on [WaitForConnectionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.waitforconnectionasync?view=net-7.0):

> Cancellation requests using the cancellation token will only work if the NamedPipeServerStream object was created with a pipe option value of PipeOptions.Asynchronous or if the cancellation occurs before the WaitForConnectionAsync method is called.

Try this:

```
using var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("", PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
```

Comment: Interesting! That did the trick. I wonder if that's new...

Comment: That remark appears to be the same for everything back to .NET Framework 4.6, which I believe was where WaitForConnectionAsync was added.

Comment: Strange it works for me everywhere else. Also a bit odd that `WaitForConnectionAsync` doesn't default to ... async. Anyway, great find, thanks.